# Wordpress: Output custom field in frontend

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a File Custom Field in Wordpress using ACF plugin called: **pdf**

Now I need to print this field in the frontend.

I'm almost there using this line of code in my function.php file

```
echo the_field('pdf');
```

Problem is that I get several values printed:

```
3491, , audiometria-1, , , application/pdf, http://example/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/audiometria-1.pdf
```

I guess this an object or array since it is comma separated.

I need to echo just the last value which the **url of the file**.

What am I missing here?

I searched in the documentation page for this plugin but I see no way to add parameters to **the_field** function: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to output the file URL onto the page (or into like an anchor, '*href*') then you'll need to get that part of the array using something to the effect of:

```
$file = get_field('pdf');
echo $file['file'];
```

***However***, that's *if you're not using the ACF plugin*. In the ACF plugin it let's you specify the output type of the field. Go to the custom field settings and change the return value to File URL.

[image: ACF plugin UI for File fields]

Save it, then all you need to do is:

```
echo the_field('pdf');
```

You can read the full [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/) about it here.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I need it.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a string not an array and you could extract the link using something like:

```
$fdata = explode(",", the_field('pdf'));
$link = array_pop($fdata);
echo $link;
```